# has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, backend

full erorr

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https:/domain/errors/403/' (redirected from 'http://domain/includes/action.php') from origin 'domain' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://domain' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

the code should to search without refresh so in localhost all work right but when i go to server i got this erorr in console

here is my php where i got a response to my main page

```php-template
<?php
    include 'db.php';
    if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $Name = $_POST['search'];
    $Query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE '%$Name%' OR namea LIKE '%$Name%' LIMIT 6";
    $q2 = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE namea LIKE '%$Name%' LIMIT 6";
    $ExecQuery = mysqli_query($con, $Query);
    $ExecQuery2 = mysqli_query($con, $q2);
    if ($ExecQuery) {
        $go = $ExecQuery;
    } else {
        $go = $ExecQuery2;
    }
    echo '<ul class="cards">';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($go)) {
        $name = $row['name'];
        $p = $row['price'];
        $d = $row['descrip'];
        $m = $row['img'];
        echo '
        <li class="cards__item">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="pimg/' . $m . '" class="card__image">
            <div class="card__content">
                <div class="card__title">name: ' . $name . '</div>
                <div class="card__title">price: ' . $p . ' $</div>
                <p class="card__text">' . $d . '</p>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>';
    }
}
```

here is my js code to send the data to search.php and got the response

```js
function fill(Value) {
    $('#search').val(Value);
    $('#display').hide();
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").keyup(function () {
        var name = $('#search').val();
        if (name != "") {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "includes/search.php",
                data: {
                    search: name
                },
                success: function (html) {
                    $("#display").html(html).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross-Origin Request Headers(CORS) with PHP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cross-origin-request-headerscors-with-php-headers)

Comment: **Warning**: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterised **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. [Escaping is not enough](https://phpdelusions.net/top#escaping)

Comment: There's not enough information here to begin debugging. Where does `includes/action.php` come into it and why is it redirecting to `errors/403/`?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the code is fully error free, then please try something like following. I don't know exactly it solve your issue. Just try.

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'db.php';

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
   // do the things you needfull
}

ob_end_flush();
```

You will get more information about [**Cross-Origin Request Headers(CORS) with PHP headers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cross-origin-request-headerscors-with-php-headers) from here. Please check the answers in the link above mentioned.

Comment: What about pre-flight `OPTIONS` requests?